# Is there a particular day of the month that has been shown not to be adequate for buying ETFs?

Tags: etf, dollar-cost-averaging

This question refers specifically to buying ETFs. When performing dollar-cost-averaging, one typically chooses a day of the month to rebalance.

The question is pretty simple: Are there any specific dates and or moments that should be avoided?

An answer in [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/10112/do-you-micro-manage-index-fund-purchases-to-a-particular-day-of-the-month) asserts that one should not buy ETFs at the trading day's opening, for example. Is this also true for particular days?

Answer (score 1):

What time of the day or what day of the week is best to trade on is a function of coincidence.   For an example, Google "The Super Bowl Indicator" which was accurate in  28 of its first 31 years.

An interesting ETF timing strategy has been buying SPY at the close and selling it at the next day’s open significantly outperforming the strategy of doing the opposite (since 1993). And yet in this year's Feb/Mar drop, this strategy performed much worse than in previous years.

So while any random event can have higher odds of success, it's also possible to have stretches of poor performance.  Like another question posed today about curve fitting, you'll only know the ideal answer in hindsight.